# Computing array of relationships from tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

I'm working on a [d3-force visualisation](https://github.com/d3/d3-force), which requires
data in a specific shape. I've got an array of objects, each with an array of tags.

```js
nodes = [
  { name: "post1", tag_list: ["activity", "online"] },
  { name: "post2", tag_list: ["workshop", "online"] },
  { name: "post3", tag_list: ["english", "workshop"] },
  ...
]
```

To establish connections between data, I need to explicitly define an array of links:

```js
links = [
  { 
    source: 'post1', 
    target: 'post2' 
  },
  { 
    source: 'post2', 
    target: 'post3' 
  },
  ...
]
```

There is no difference in similarity between links - all relationships are linear and carry the same *"agency"*. Identical data should ideally be filtered to prevent duplicate lines.

How can I generate a link array of the previously mentioned shape from the `tag_list` arrays?

[Here's an example of the required data structure.](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph?collection=@d3/d3-force#miserables)

--

Some context: I'm trying to visualise thematic overlaps between blog pages. All pages have an array of tags to describe them (`tag_list`). I wish to connect all tags within the graph. Since `d3` requires verbose references to draw links (see link below), I need to compute these from the tag lists that are accessible to me.

Comment: What if more than two posts contain the same tag? Can you provide more source and expected data?

Comment: What is your measure of similarity between two posts? The number of identical tags?

Comment: I've added some more data and description to my post, including some context. I hope it clarifies my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect each tag, and for each tag collect the distinct names (in a Set). When such a tag already has names associated to it, iterate those and pair it with the "current" name, putting the lexically smaller name as first pair-member. Store this pair in a map of Sets, so that they are unique.

Here is an implementation:

```js
let nodes = [
  { name: "post1", tag_list: ["activity", "online"] },
  { name: "post2", tag_list: ["workshop", "online"] },
  { name: "post3", tag_list: ["english", "workshop"] },
];

let tags = {};
let pairs = {};
let result = [];
for (let {name, tag_list} of nodes) {
    for (let tag of tag_list) {
        for (let other of tags[tag] ??= new Set) {
            let [source, target] = [name, other].sort();
            if (!(pairs[source] ??= new Set).has(target)) {
                pairs[source].add(target);
                result.push({source, target});
            }
        }
        tags[tag].add(name);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash grouping approach. First make an object where keys are hashes of the links, and then use only the values as the result.

```js
const nodes = [
  { name: "post1", tag_list: ["activity", "online"] },
  { name: "post2", tag_list: ["workshop", "online"] },
  { name: "post3", tag_list: ["online"] },
  { name: "post4", tag_list: ["workshop"] },
  { name: "post5", tag_list: ["lonely"] },
];

const hasIntersection = (arrA, arrB) => arrA.some((el) => arrB.includes(el));

const groupedByHash = nodes.reduce((acc, targetNode) => {
  const commonNodes = nodes
    .filter(({ tag_list }) => hasIntersection(tag_list, targetNode.tag_list))
    .filter(({ name }) => name !== targetNode.name);

  if (commonNodes.length < 1) return acc;
  
  const commonLinks = commonNodes.reduce((acc, { name }) => {
    const [source, target] = [name, targetNode.name].sort();
    const hash = [source, target].join('---');
    acc[hash] = { source, target };
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
  return { ...acc, ...commonLinks };
}, {});

const result = Object.values(groupedByHash);


console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```